# PHP MySQL DELETE row from html table with link button

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I've been looking at this for some time now, all I'm doing is learning PHP with mysql, with no previous programming experience before these so please be kind. I need to delete an entire row from a table. The table is inside `list.php` and there's a delete button that redirects to `delete.php`. But all it does it redirects me to a blank page with an url something like `"delete.php?id=4"` depending on row ID, which seems to be correct.

This is `connect.php`:

```
<?php 
$server = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "school";

$db_conn = mysqli_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

$connect_error = 'Sorry, we are experiencing connection problems';

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die($connect_error);
mysql_select_db('school') or die($connect_error);

?>
```

And this is `delete.php` :

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['ID'])){
    $courseID = $_GET['ID'];
    $sql_delete = "DELETE FROM Courses WHERE ID = $courseID";       
    print ($sql_delete);        
        $result = mysqli_query($db_conn,$sql_delete);
    if($result) {
        echo "Congratulations. You have deleted this course succesfully.";
        header('location:list.php');
    } else {
        echo "Error";
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
    }

}
?>
```

Notice  "`print ($sql_delete);`", which doesn't print anything either. All I can think of is there is something wrong with the way I am asking for the ID by using `$_GET`, but can't get my head around it. When I run

> ```
> "DELETE FROM Courses WHERE ID = 4;"
> ```

inside xampp's mysql module, it works. Uhm... oh well.

OK, let me add:
This is actually my delete button inside list.php, which gives me an URL based on table row number, based on Course id.

```
<?php echo "<td><a href=\"delete.php?id=$row[ID]\">Delete</a>";?>
```

Comment: `$_GET['ID']` must be `$_GET['id']`

Comment: Hey Paul, thanks for answering. It doesn't redirect me to a blank page anymore which means that header now works, but it doesn't delete the row either. :-/

Comment: Are you testing with an ID that exists? Meaning: if you already deleted the row with ID of 4, are you testing with ID 4?

Comment: You also need to avoid sql injection. `$courseID = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);`

Comment: timgavin, you missed the details of the question. I only inserted a number manually inside SQL command line to check whether there was something wrong with the query. I need to make it work automatically with $_GET, by making the code read the ID automatically from the URL. As I already mentioned, URL redirection works properly.

Comment: I was going by this: "inside xampp's mysql module, it works" :)

Comment: You need to include connect.php in delete.php

Comment: That was done already, don't know how I ommitted it: The first line in delete.php is actually require('connect.php');

Comment: Write `echo mysqli_affected_rows($db_conn) . "<br>" . $sql_delete; exit;` after `$result = mysqli_query(...);` line, and look what happens.

Comment: Hey Paul, it says, "Congratulations.". Also, I tried to echo $courseID right after $courseID = $_GET['id']; and it doesn't do it, maybe this helps identifying the problem?

Comment: replace `echo $courseID` with `var_dump($courseID)`.

Comment: still nothing. Well, only congratulating me on my success, lol.

Comment: deactivate `header('location:list.php');` :-)

Comment: did that too. Otherwise I wouldn't have gotten the congratulations message.

Comment: if `var_dump` is showing nothing, then it is not executed.

Comment: You mention that the pave you get redirected to delete.php in order to perform the delete? So you don't get the success message? But you don't get the error message either in your if else?

The query itself looks fine. Can you try to echo something random inside your if isset? That way you know if you even enter anything as a start. If you don't enter it at all, try,

if(isset($_GET['id'])){

instead of

if(isset($_GET['ID'])){

I do believe that the $_GET method is case-sensitive, and by the looks of it, you parse it as id= and not ID= in your button.

Answer (score 0):

connect.php

```
    $server = "localhost";
    $db_user = "root";
    $db_pass = "";
    $db_name = "school";
    $db_conn = mysqli_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
```

delete.php

```
if(isset($_GET['ID'])){
  $courseID = $_GET['ID'];
  $sql_delete = "DELETE FROM Courses WHERE ID = $courseID";        
  $result = mysqli_query($db_conn,$sql_delete);
  if(mysqli_affected_rows($db_conn)>0) {
      header('location:list.php?result=success');
  } else {
     header('location:list.php?result=fail');
  }
 }
```

list.php (Where is delete button)

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['result'))
{
if($_GET['result']=='success')
{

    echo "Congratulations. You have deleted this course succesfully.";
}
else{
     echo "error";
  }
}
?>
(Delete button)
<a href="delete.php?ID=5" >Delete</a>
```